# Some problems about Next Round in BoutTime game swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function:

```
func setupRound() {
    let period =  historicalEvents.randomEvent()
    displayEvents(period: period)
}

// action method
@IBAction func nextRound() {
  setupRound()
}
```

When I try to click button NextRound -> Screen do not set new events. I think problem in model class : HistoricalEvents or something like override constants,... because I try to debug and it moved on setupRound function

Please check my code on GitHub Source code : https://github.com/baonguyen150028/BoutTime

Comment: swift lang version ..?

Comment: @vaibhav swift 3 man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged your program and found out that in your 'randomIndexPeriod' function, 'check' variable always hold true, which results in infinite loop in your program. The reason is that 'previousPeriodNumber' array contains same value as 'randomPeriodNumber' value so that 'check' variable become always true.

Comment: Thank you so much :D Hope you have a nice day.